# Apache Ant is there any way to get a build to ignore errors

Tags: java, git, ant, jakarta-ee

I have a strange situation where I can build a project with ant without any errors on my development machine but when I push the exact same source to the production server I can't get it to build on that side. 
I get 'cannot find symbol' errors related to specific syntax.
I set up a git repo on the production server then cloned it. So I really don't get how I could build it on my side but not the production server side, since I got the code from the production server in the first place, and it was running previously. 
The code that causes the build to fail is not from the commit I pushed. I tried changing back to the master which has been unchanged since the original files were added to the repo and it still won't build for the same reason.
So since I can't start the server again without the build completing & the reason that it fails has to do with code unlikely to be used any time soon. Is it possible to get ant to continue to build ignoring errors? Or does anyone have an other ideas what the problem could be? (I need to get the server running again even if it's unstable)

Comment: If the code is really _unlikely to be used_, can you remove the Ant commands that _build_ the file in question and excise all references to it from elsewhere in the source?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the same source is unable to compile on two different machines, that points to a difference in the environment settings between the two machines: either there are different libraries being compiled against on the two machines (which one would hope is not the case if you are using a tool like Ant, you should be specifying the exact libraries your code needs), or you are using different versions of the JDK to compile against.

I suggest resolving the environmental problems rather than hacking Ant to ignore errors.

Answer (score 6):

You can add `failonerror="false"` to specific tasks

I don't really understand your problem though, so can't provide an answer for the fix. Seems like environmental issues, if you can add details, people can help you solve the actual problem.

Answer (score 0):

Can you post your error so that it helps us to answer better? Symbol could mean that something was not installed properly or it does not have the proper execution privileges. It is not advisable to suppress the errors, because that will lead to a totally unstable solution. Please post the error.